# Installed .Net Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012, My WPF version is still showing 3.0

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I followed the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349641.aspx and found out that my WPF version is 3.0.6920.2011 even though I have already installed .Net Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. How can that be?  I can not write XAML to exploit the new features like Ribbon (cannot find it in the toolbox) with current version of WPF.  Thanks.

Comment: My money says that the linked documentation is either wrong or obsolete. I have VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 installed on a VM, and I know that WPF is installed, but I don't have a "Windows Presentation Foundation" key in that location.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, if I would like to use new functionalities in WPF 4.5, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on *References* in your project in *solution Explorer*, choose *Add Reference*, then enter *Assemblies -> Framework*, find *PresentationCore*/*PresentationFramework*. There you can find version used by your projects.

Note that in some cases - for example if you want to use *Ribbon* presented in newer WPF, you will have to add suitable reference.